# Вызов аудио-файла для беспроблемной упаковки в .jar

Tags: java, аудио

Создал класс `ResourceLoader` для получения пути к картинкам:

```
public class ResourceLoader {
    static ResourceLoader rl = new ResourceLoader();
    public static Image getImage(String fileName){
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(rl.getClass().getResource("images/" + fileName));
    }
}
```

Как сделать такое же получение пути для wav-файлов из папки sounds?

Comment: Вариант поменять `"images/"` на  `"sounds/"` не пподходит?

Comment: чем вы потом собираетесь звук проигрывать?

Answer (score 1):

Ок, опишу,

```
URL resource = Object.class.getResource("/sounds/".concat(NAMESOUNDS));
try {
      BufferedInputStream sounds = new BufferedInputStream((InputStream) resource.openStream()); //ОТКРЫВАЕМ БУФЕРЕЗИРОВАННЫЙ ПОТОК
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

А дальше мне не известно где вы будете использовать открытый wav в оперативной памяти. Ответ один делайте что-то основанное на Clip.

И P.S все что находится в jar это вам не каталог не просмотришь файлы которые в sounds в jar, делаешь в этом каталоге класс model который возвращает тебе ссылки.